# Appbar leading CircleAvatar onTap is not working Flutter

Tags: flutter-appbar

[AppBar Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CB0AW.png)

I'm trying to open up a drawer once the profile image in the AppBar is tapped.

```
appBar: AppBar(
leading: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 20),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => const MyDrawer(),
            child: const CircleAvatar(
              backgroundImage: AssetImage('assets/images/Profile_Image.png'),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Once tapped, the function MyDrawer() is not being called. I have tried wrapping the CircleAvatar with InkWell but it doesn't seem to work too.

The function MyDrawer() did work when the drawer property was used.